# Отличие Name от x:Name

Tags: wpf

В чем заключается отличение `Name` от `x:Name`?

Answer (score 14):

Резюме: Хороший вопрос. Отличие при нормальных сценариях использования чисто теоретическое, можно не обращать внимание.

---

Более длинный ответ.

`x:Name` отвечает за то, чтобы вы могли сослаться на это имя в вашем code-behind, а также за привязку по `ElementName`. XAML-атрибут `Name`, как и все остальные атрибуты без `x:`, устанавливает значение свойства `Name`. В WPF вшита магия, которая выполняет и то, и другое, когда вы укажете любой из атрибутов.

---

Ответ со всеми подробностями.

Атрибуты в [пространстве имён WPF (то есть, в пространстве имён `httр://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx#The_WPF_and_XAML_Namespace_Declarations) (которое обычно является пространством имён по умолчанию), отображаются на *свойства* WPF-объектов (наподобие [`Grid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx)). Поскольку базовые типы WPF-классов (например, [`FrameworkElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.aspx)) содержат dependency property `Name`, указание этого атрибута возможно для всех WPF-классов.

Атрибуты в [пространстве имён XAML (`httр://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753327.aspx) (которое обычно кодируется алиасом `x`) относятся к атрибутам XAML-тегов. Они несут [специальный XAML-специфический смысл](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753327.aspx). В частности, `x:Name` задаёт XAML-имя внутри текущего [NameScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx). При обычном сценарии использования XAML (компиляция XAML-файла с build action = Page) атрибуты `x:Name` превращаются в поле объемлющего класса, которое в методе `InitializeComponent` инициализируется ссылкой на WPF-объект, сконструированный из XAML-тега с этим атрибутом. Кроме того, XAML-имя используется для поиска [`ElementName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx) для `Binding`'ов: связи типа `ElementName` разрешаются на этапе компиляции.

Для избежания противоречий и ошибок, было решено, что обе декларации действуют одинаково: во время компиляции XAML любой из `Name` и `x:Name` выполняет обе роли: устанавливает dependency property `Name`, и создаёт поле в объемлющем классе и его привязку.

Для того, чтобы задать эту связь, используется [`RuntimeNamePropertyAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.runtimenamepropertyattribute.aspx). Вы можете, переопределив этот атрибут, назначить для `x:Name` другое свойство.

В принципе возможны сценарии, в которых в XAML "попадёт" объект, не имеющий свойства `Name` и атрибута `RuntimeNamePropertyAttribute`. В этом случае, понятно, будет работать только `x:Name`. Например, объекты типа [`Storyboard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.aspx) или [`Transform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transform.aspx) не порождены от [`FrameworkElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.aspx)/[`FrameworkContentElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkcontentelement.aspx) и не имеют свойства `Name`, тем не менее, указав `x:Name` для них, вы сможете сослаться на них в code-behind.

Заметьте, что связь между `x:Name` и `Name` существует лишь постольку, поскольку она поддерживается фреймворком WPF. Заметьте, что даже некомпилированный XAML, загружаемый WPF, регистрирует значения `x:Name` в `NameScope` (так как это значение потенциально важно для `Binding` `ElementName`), но в этом случае не будет выполнена кастомная привязка к полям объекта, выполняемая обычно в `InitializeComponent()`.