# Переменная из xaml отсутствует в контексте cs файла

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго времени суток. Прошу помочь, я определяю в xaml файле переменную

а потом, когда в cs файле пытаюсь изменить свойство visibility, выдает ошибку "Переменная отсутствует в текущем контексте"

Подскажите, в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Покажите код. Что это за "переменная" и как вы ее "определяете в xaml"?

Comment: Переменная - control, определяю - описываю. Прошу прощения за неверный лексикон

Answer (score 2):

Все оказалось очень просто, в xaml файле нужно указывать параметр x:Name, а не Name

Comment: Вы используете `Transform`? Обычно разницы нет, кроме этого случая. Вот по теме: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/206566/10105