# При изучении WPF появились некоторые вопросы

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Изучаю WPF и столкнулся со следующем:

1)Прямо в XAML можно писать программный код.

Такой подход в каких-то случаях оправдан? Понятное дело, что писать всю логику в XAML- нехорошо.

2)Как я понял через XamlReader можно на основании Xaml файлов динамически создавать формы.

Есть ли у этого метода какие-то ограничения? Например, можно ли во время работы изменить текущую форму, загрузив другую разметку и т п?

3)Я правильно понимаю, что атрибут `x:Name` является опциональным? Т.е если я хочу работать с элементом в коде, то даю ему имя, а если не хочу, то игнорирую?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Смотря что вы имеете в виду под кодом. В XAML имеет смысл писать только разметку, то есть, декларативное описание. Из «логики» разве что триггеры в стилях или там привязки. Код с логикой пишется C# в code-behind.

Если речь идёт о конструкции `x:Code`, процитирую [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa970568(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4):

> Следует избегать или ограничивать использование встроенного кода. В терминах архитектуры и философии кодирования обеспечение разделения между разметкой и выделенным кодом лучше разделяет роли конструктора и разработчика. На более техническом уровне код, написанный для встроенного кода, может быть неудобным в плане записи, поскольку разработчик всегда пишет в создаваемом разделяемом классе XAML и может использовать только сопоставления пространства имен XML по умолчанию. [...]

2) Да, но. При этом вы теряете весь code-behind, так что вы ограничены стандартными контролами. Более новые версии XAML, кажется, поддерживают вставки кода, но они не поддерживаются фреймворком WPF.

Ну и для смены текущей формы есть другие, стандартные выразительные средства, без ручного чтения XAML. Например, подгрузка нужного UI в зависимости от `DataContext`'а через `DataTemplate`.

3) Да, `x:Name` опционален. И в большинстве случаев вместо `x:Name` [можно писать просто `Name`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/206566/10105).

Comment: А привязку обработчиков событий так же делают не в разметке, а в коде?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Обычно в разметке. `<Button Click="OnCloseClick">Close</Button>`.

Comment: Хм... даже если обработчиков несколько? Каша не возникнет?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Вроде бы не возникала. В любом случае довольно часто в XAML'е будет устанавливаться много свойств, так что один-другой обработчик — не большая проблема.